# Unexpected error launching internet explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a very weird situation while running the script in spoon IE browsers in my local.

I am opening the Spoon browser  through the Selenium standalone server  in port 4444 and the server(selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar) is running fine in the same port without any warning or error message.

But while i am trying to execute the script in IE9 spoon it is throwing some error message like "Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012 ('There are no more files.') for URL  (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)".

I have set all the protected mode as enabled, zoom level 100% from Internet Options and i am using the below code to open the IE browser in Spoon.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
                capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
                capabilities.setCapability("silent", true);
```

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("IpAddress of the machine:4444/wd/hub"),capabilities);

Browser is opening perfectly but no url is loading and throwing the above error message. The script is running fine in local(native) IE.

Machine Configuration:

Windows7 32 bit

IEDriver 32 bit

Selenim standalone server version: selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar

Java Version: 1.6.0_45

Selenium Jar version: 2.42.2

The interesting part is I tried in some other machine by starting the Spoon IE in 4444 port and the script ran perfectly without any error message and i am having the configuration exactly same as the other machine.

Can anyone please help me out how to fix this error?

Thanks,

Sudhansu

Comment: Did you compare the configuration of both the machines.? Did you observe any difference.??

Comment: that was 64 bit and mine is 32 bit OS